# Managing Python modules in RPM environment

Tags: python, pip, rpm, yum, koji

I'm deploying all my Python code as RPM's in `CentOS 6/7` + I'm using Fedora's Koji to build them. All works fine unless you want to use `virtualenv` or `Software Collections` Some problems:

- If I don't use SCL's I'm bound to System Python versions - `Python 2.6` and `2.7`
- If I want to use `Software Collections` to have newer Python, all rpm's I built are useless because they are built in `Koji` and then installed in the system python path
- If I want to use `virtualenv` for development, again rpms don't come in handy - imagine I have my own config_manager module distributed by RPM. I activate the `virtualenv` and I have no way to install my module in a correct place (because my config_manager is not in pip and RPM installs in a default system location)

Any suggestions on how to deal with this situation? So far the only thing I came up with is to install my modules in a custom directory. Then in my Python main executable script, I include this directory in the path.

This way even if someone is in `virtualenv` or `Software Collection` my code won't fail from missing dependencies.
But then it can generate compatibility issues between Python versions.

Is there any way to solve this properly? Any tips?

Comment: The way I solved this problem years ago was to do a proper side install of Python (not like the SCL in /opt, but in a non-disruptive system path like the gcc44 package for EL5) and build the rpm with mock. The way you would solve this problem now is to just use Docker.

Comment: Software Collection package are installed in /opt. See https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/docs/guide/#sect-The_File_System_Hierarchy

Comment: Have you seen https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Python ? It doesn't talk about SCL unfortunately, but has some notes about having python3 coexisting.